create a sequence using seq() but starting at a number other than one
I want to create a sequence starting at 10 and that sequence be the length of a vector.
length(myVec) = 3

seq(length(myVec), 10)

However my issue here is that the sequence counts down from 10 to 3 whereas I need it to do from 10 to 12, which is the length of myVec, like so;
seq(length(myVec), 10)
10, 11, 12


Please include the vector myVec, otherwise potential answers might assume the wrong starting point.

Lots of ways to solve this, but here's one:
> seq(from = 10, length.out = 3)
[1] 10 11 12

You can obviously change the hardcoded values to variables to better fit your use case.

Simply use : and basic iteration logic:
> l = 3
> i = 10 
> i:(i+l-1)
[1] 10 11 12


You could use
myVec <- 1:3
seq(myVec) + 9
# [1] 10 11 12

Or maybe create a helper function like
countUp <- function(x, start=10) seq(x) + start - 1
countUp(myVec)
# [1] 10 11 12


Your question seems to imply that myVec already exists but you didn't include an actual value in your example. So in order to share runnable code, i just defined myVec to be a simple vector of length three. I guess it wasn't clear what the input was to your question.

I could have defined myVec <- c(19, 29349, -5). I'm just used to explicitly using 1:3 for making quick vectors. To me it's more clear what it returns than seq(3). Not everyone is used to 1-based counting.

1-based counting was the missing argument to me. Thank you.
